How to display the uuid field of my serializer as a string in a get request with django restframework
Here is my serializer
class AgenceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    uuid = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex',allow_null=True,required=False) <-------
    p1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=50,required=True)
    p2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=50,required=True)

views.py
@api_view(["POST"])
def details_agence(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        serializer = AgenceUUIDSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            agence_repr = serializer.agence_details(data=request.data)
            serializer = AgenceSerializer(agence_repr)
            print(serializer)
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_200_OK) <---------
 ...

a print on the serializer gives me the following:
AgenceSerializer({'uuid': 'A75DF036-6C16-4311-9825-22B1295D8A26', 'p1': 'Ozangue', ...}):
    uuid = UUIDField(allow_null=True, format='hex', required=False)
    ...

But when I display the data, in the response, the uuid field is always null
How to solve this problem ?

uudi -> uuid.

just add this to your serializer
class AgenceSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    uuid = serializers.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, format='hex',allow_null=True,required=False) 
    p1 = serializers.CharField(max_length=50,required=True)
    p2 = serializers.CharField(max_length=50,required=True)

Notice the uuid field.

I had same problem and this helped me.
uuid = serializers.CharField()  # Change UUIDField to CharField
